# Perl Regex to test if array is uniform

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

I have a piece of code that´s not working and I can´t figure out why.
It's probably a regex problem but as far as I know it should be working.

I have an array which holds `<typenumber>:<KitName>`, for example `2:K1663`

I want to match the `KitName` of every entry in this array to the `KitName` of the first entry. For this I have a regex that should return everything past the colon `:`. I then use an `if` to compare the current entry `$_` to the first entry `$KitHit[0]`.

Then, if there was any mismatch the `$booly` will be set to 1 and all the entries will be printed.

However, even if the Kits are all the same I still get the entries printed.
I added a `print "A"` or `print "B"` to see when the match code and when the mismatch code is ran. This returns `B A B A B A B A B` without any regard for my data.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong? I can't figure it out no matter what I try.

```
my @KitHold;
my $booly = 0;

open( $outputfile_fh, ">>", $outputfile ) or die "Could not open file     '$outputfile' $!";    

foreach ( (), @KitHit ) {

    my $KitHelp;

    if ( ( $_ =~ /(?<=:)\w+/g ) eq ( $KitHit[0] =~ /(?<=:)\w+/g ) ) {
        $KitHelp = $separator[$1] . "\[$categories[$1]\]:" . $_ . "\n" if $_ =~ /(\d+)/;
        push (@KitHold,$KitHelp);
        print "\nA;
    }
    else {
        $KitHelp = $separator[$1] . "\[$categories[$1]\]:" . $_ . "\n" if $_ =~ /(\d+)/;
        push( @KitHold, $KitHelp );
        $booly = 1;
        print "\nB";
    }
}

if ( $booly == 1 ) {
    print {$outputfile_fh} "\n\nKits not uniform:\n@KitHold";
} 

close $outputfile_fh;
```

Example data:

#### `@KitHit` with mismatches:

```
    2:K1663
    3:K1675
    4:K1663
    5:K1663
    6:K1663
    7:K1663
    8:K1675
    13:K1675
    14:K1675
```

#### `@KitHit` with uniform entries:

```
    2:K1663
    3:K1663
    4:K1663
    5:K1663
    6:K1663
    7:K1663
    8:K1663
    13:K1663
    14:K1663
```

I should also mention that the Kit names could eventually come to include more than just a K and 4 numbers, hence why my regex looks at everything after the colon.

Comment: What's the output for your sample data? I'm having a bit of a hard time following your code, but this smells like an XY problem. Like - you talk about "KitName" but it's unclear what that actually is. This looks like a job for a hash, not an array though.

Comment: @Sobrique: The OP simply wants to check whether the part of each array element after the colon is the same throughout the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not achieve the result with a regex-only solution?

```
\A\s*(?>[^\s:]+:(?(1)\1|(\S+))\s*)+\z
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xuLXI/1) (no mismatch)

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xuLXI/2) (having mismatch)

Answer (score 2):

So if I'm reading you correctly - you're trying to check if all the "K" numbers are the same, or not.

I'd actually suggest that a "magic regex" isn't the solution here - it's doable, but it's inevitably going to be quite hard to follow, and hard to modify later.

Instead, I'd say your data is ideal for inserting into a [`hash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) in perl, because... well, it *is* key value pairs, and thats what hashes are for.

So with that in mind, I'd tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

#read it into a hash
my %data = map { /(\d+):(\w+)/ } <>;
# <> is the magic file handle, that reads 'STDIN'
#or files specified to command line. 
#you can do the same with any FH that you've opened though. 

#for debug
print Dumper \%data;

#count values. 
my %count_of;
$count_of{$_}++ for values %data;

#for debug
print Dumper \%count_of;

#if there's more than one key here, we
#have a mismatch
if ( keys %count_of > 1 ) {
    print "Mismatch spotted:\n";
    foreach my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b} keys %data ) { 
        print "$key:$data{$key}\n";
    }
}
```

I've assumed here you can read in from a file. If that's not a valid assumption, then you can do the same thing with `@KitHit` and map:

```
my %data = map { /(\d+):(\w+)/ } @KitHit;
```

And do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your test

```
if ( ( $_ =~ /(?<=:)\w+/g ) eq ( $KitHit[0] =~ /(?<=:)\w+/g ) ) {
```

is comparing the results of two regex pattern matches. Those results are boolean indications of whether the strings matched the pattern

You are testing whether the values in the array contain a colon `:` followed by at least one "word" character. Since all of them do, the result of both matches will always be 1. Your comparison compares `'1' eq '1'` and always results in *true*

There are a number of other problems with your code

- You should show a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can try your code ourselves
- You must `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, and declare every variablee with `my` as close as possible to its first point of use
- Most Perl programmers are more familiar with lexical variables named with lower-case letters, digits, and underscores. It is especially important to avoid a capital initial letter. So `@KitHit` should be `@kit_hit`
- You open the output file right at the start of the program, but don't write to it until the end. And did you mean to open it for *appending*?
- In the line `foreach ( (), @KitHit ) {`, the `()` is ineffective and should be removed
- You do the calculation of `$KitHelp` and the push onto `@KitHold` identically in both branches of the `if`. These should be done just once, separately, either before or after the `if`
- You should make use of variable interpolation to build strings instead of the concatenation operator `.`. Also note that square brackets don't need to be escaped inside double quotes, so

  ```
   $KitHelp = $separator[$1] . "\[$categories[$1]\]:" . $_ . "\n"
  ```

  could be written as

  ```
   $KitHelp = "$separator[$1][$categories[$1]]:$_\n"
  ```
- Your flag variable `$booly` should have a more meaningful name, like `$mismatch`

You haven't shown the contents of `@separator` or `@categories` so I can't properly test this code, but it looks correct and compiles

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @hit_hold;
my (@separator, @categories);    # Need initialising

my @kit_hit = qw/
    2:K1663
    3:K1675
    4:K1663
    5:K1663
    6:K1663
    7:K1663
    8:K1675
    13:K1675
    14:K1675
/;

my $mismatch;

my ($output_file) = @ARGV;    # Take output file name from command line

die unless my ($n0, $key0) = $kit_hit[0] =~ /^(\d+):(.+)/;

for ( @kit_hit ) {

    next unless my ($n, $key) = /^(\d+):(.+)/;

    push @hit_hold, "$separator[$n][$categories[$1]]:$_\n";

    if ( $key eq $key0 ) {
        print "\nA";
    }
    else {
        $mismatch = 1;
        print "\nB";
    }
}

if ( $mismatch ) {

    open my $out_fh, '>', $output_file or die qq{Could not open "$output_file" for output: $!};    
    my $old_fh = select $out_fh;

    print "\n\n";
    print "Kits not uniform:\n";
    print "$_\n" for @hit_hold;
    close $out_fh;

    select $old_fh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach to match every value with the first value.

Say, the first value is :

```
K1663
```

Then you can loop through the rest of the indexes and apply this regex to determine if that is a match. If that is a match you can print it.

```
use strict;


my $regex = qr/^(\d+):(?!K1663$)(.*)$/mp;

my $str = '3:K1675';
# your loop goes here : where each $str contains the current index value
if( $str =~ /$regex/g )
  print "$1 $2 \n";
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZT8yZg/1)

[Demo Impl](http://ideone.com/Wn1sFz)